# Getting error in applyEdits function for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have been trying to add an entry to a featureLayer and in want to get a callback from this so I can update another field in it. below is my code

```
clkListenerAddFeature = dojo.connect(map, "onClick", function (evt)
{
    //alert("inside the click function");
    var point = evt.mapPoint;

    var attributes = {};
    attributes["1"] = "CLOSED";
    attributes["2"] = "DENIED"; 
    attributes["3"] = "0";
    attributes["4"] = "1";
    attributes["5"] = userLoginId;

    var graphic = new esri.Graphic(point, null, attributes);
    featureLayerEdit.applyEdits([graphic], null, null);
    dojo.connect(featureLayerEdit, "onEditsComplete", addResultsComplete);

    if (clkListenerAddFeature) dojo.disconnect(clkListenerAddFeature);
    refresh_map();
    reset_map(map);

});

function addResultsComplete(addResults)
{
    if (addResults.length > 0) {
        var graphic = featureLayerEdit.graphics[featureLayerEdit.graphics.length - 1];

        graphic.attributes["6"] = graphic.attributes["OBJECTID"];
        featureLayerEdit.applyEdits(null, [graphic], null);
    }

}
```

but I keep hitting this error `TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'getCellsInExtent': object is null or undefined`

anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I think the error of getCellsInExtent is null or undefined is causing the callback to fail. so if i add a point how should I go about adding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be with your attributes. Are 1,2,3,4,5 really the field names in your feature service?

It should be something more like

```
attributes["FIELD_NAME_1"] = "CLOSED";
//equivalent to... 
attributes.FIELD_NAME_1 = "CLOSED";
```

Btw, instead of connecting onEditsComplete, I find attaching anonymous function to callback and errback more concise/readable.

```
var d = new Date();
var attr = {
    Created_By: "awesomo",
    Created_Date: d.getTime()
};
var graphic = new esri.Graphic(addGeom, null, attr, null);
featureLayerEdit.applyEdits([graphic], null, null, function (adds, updates, deletes) {
    var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
    query.objectIds = [adds[0].objectId];
    featureLayerEdit.selectFeatures(query, esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
    alert("Added feature successfully, OBJECTID: " + adds[0].objectId);
}, function (err) {
    //when an error occurs
    alert("Apply Edits Failed: " + err.message);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, yepp in the end i decided to attach the callback and errback functions to the applyEdits function.